# Ionic 3 Lazy Loading with amDateFormat pipe

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I am using Ionic3, and am in the process of converting to Lazy Loading in order to improve startup performance.

I am experiencing a problem with pipes after converting my `ChatsPage` to lazy loading.  As you can see below, it is complaining about the use of the following line in my `chats.html`.

```
    <h3 class="chat-time">{{item.timestamp | amDateFormat: 'D MMM YYYY'}}</h3>
```

> ```
> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
> The pipe 'amDateFormat' could not be found ("item.memberId2 && !item.lastMsg_read2))}">{{item.lastMsg_text}}</p>
>         <h3 class="chat-time">{{[ERROR ->]item.timestamp | amDateFormat: 'D MMM YYYY'}}</h3>
>       </ion-item>
>
> "): ng:///ChatsPageModule/ChatsPage.html@28:32
> Error: Template parse errors:
> The pipe 'amDateFormat' could not be found ("item.memberId2 && !item.lastMsg_read2))}">{{item.lastMsg_text}}</p>
>         <h3 class="chat-time">{{[ERROR ->]item.timestamp | amDateFormat: 'D MMM YYYY'}}</h3>
>       </ion-item>
> ```

**Question**

Any idea how to handle `amDateFormat` (angular2-moment) with lazy loading?

More info:

```
Your system information:

Cordova CLI: 6.4.0 
Ionic Framework Version: 3.0.1
Ionic CLI Version: 2.1.18
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.1.9
Ionic App Scripts Version: 1.3.0
ios-deploy version: Not installed
ios-sim version: Not installed
OS: macOS Sierra
Node Version: v6.9.4
Xcode version: Xcode 8.3.2 Build version 8E2002
```

Comment: The following link talks about handling custom pipes, but I am not sure how to apply this to `amDateFormat`?  https://ionicacademy.com/ionic-3-lazy-loading/

Comment: Did you try importing that module in the ngModule of page.module.ts?

Comment: Nope, I will give that a try. What exactly do I import though? `import {???} from './angular2-moment/???'`

Comment: https://github.com/urish/angular2-moment `MomentModule`

Comment: Thanks once again Suraj. That works `import {MomentModule} from 'angular2-moment';`. I appreciate your great advise as always.

Comment: ok.. will add as answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For lazy loading you need to add the module to imports of the **page.module.ts**.

```
import {MomentModule} from 'angular2-moment';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    MomentModule
  ],
```