# How can we use Provider in Pipe files while using Deep Linking and Lazy Loading Ionic 3?

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, ionic3, deep-linking

I want to use a Provider, named as `Translation.ts` with a returnResult function in a Pipe named as `TranslatePipe.ts`.  Translation.ts is

```
@Injectable()
export class TranslationProvider

  constructor() { }

  getResult(value) { returns something ; }

}
```

and TranslatePipe.ts is given as

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'translation',
})
export class TranslationPipe implements PipeTransform {

  constructor(public translateService: TranslationProvider) {

  }


  transform(value: string, ...args) {
    return this.translateService.getResult(value);
  }
```

MY project is Ionic 3 and I use Lazy Loading. My page is ExamplePage
In ExamplePage.html I want to use piping as {{'something' | translation}}

and example.ts is

```
@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'example',
  templateUrl: 'example.html',
})
export class ExamplePage {

  constructor(public translate: TranslationProvider) {  }
}
```

app.module is something like that

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    TranslatePipe,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
    IonicStorageModule.forRoot()
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [ .. ],
  providers: [
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler},
    TranslationProvider
  ]
})
```

There is something related with this subject but they dont work such as

- [Ionic 3 Lazy Loading with amDateFormat pipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43775715/ionic-3-lazy-loading-with-amdateformat-pipe) or
- [Pipe not found in custom component - Ionic 3 (Lazy Loading)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44735628/pipe-not-found-in-custom-component-ionic-3-lazy-loading)

I try to modify example.module, I added Provider and Pipe but it did not work.
Would you give me any recommendation about the solution?

Comment: in which module is pipe declared?

Comment: App.module and in page module

Comment: I think once is enough.. It doesn't work if you declare in App.module? andin which module is TranslationProvider set as provider?

Comment: In App.Module : Translation.ts is TranslationProvider

Comment: do you get any error?

Comment: core.es5.js:1020 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
The pipe 'translation' could not be found ("

Comment: I call TranslateProvider from TransatePipe file . Then problem occurs.

Comment: Can youPlease [edit] your post with app.module code and error message?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155070/discussion-between-dr-geek-and-suraj).

Comment: Maybe this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46166922/4254681) could help

Answer (score 1):

Include **both provider and pipe** in either *app.module.ts* OR *example.module.ts* based on whether you want to use in more pages or only in example page and not both.

You need to add them in the same module.

```
 declarations: [
    TranslatePipe,
  ],
  //...
  providers: [
    TranslationProvider
  ]
```