# How can we import Pipe file in different Lazy Loading Pages in ionic3?

Tags: angular, typescript, lazy-loading, ionic3

This question is very similar to [How can we use Provider in Pipe files while using Deep Linking and Lazy Loading Ionic 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46361981/how-can-we-use-provider-in-pipe-files-while-using-deep-linking-and-lazy-loading) but in this question, we don't use Provider.

I have a 2 Lazy Loading Pages Page1 and Page2 and HomePage as a root page. In addition, MyPipe file is the Pipe file. as given below. I want to use this Pipe file in LAzy Loading Files Page1 and Page2 and HomePage

**Case 1**: If I add `Pipe` file only on `app.module`

- [page1.module.t](https://gist.github.com/ugurayan/f51436e737838df52d92ad70241a5748#file-page1-module-ts)s ( no imported [Pipe file](https://gist.github.com/ugurayan/f51436e737838df52d92ad70241a5748#file-my-ts)). We use pipe in [page1.html](https://gist.github.com/ugurayan/f51436e737838df52d92ad70241a5748#file-page1-html)
- [page2.moudel.ts](https://gist.github.com/ugurayan/f51436e737838df52d92ad70241a5748#file-page2-modul-ts) ( no imported [Pipe file](https://gist.github.com/ugurayan/f51436e737838df52d92ad70241a5748#file-my-ts)). We use pipe in [page2.html](https://gist.github.com/ugurayan/f51436e737838df52d92ad70241a5748#file-page2-html)
- [app.module.ts](https://gist.github.com/ugurayan/f51436e737838df52d92ad70241a5748#file-app-module-ts) ( import [Pipe file](https://gist.github.com/ugurayan/f51436e737838df52d92ad70241a5748#file-my-ts)). we use pipe in [home.html](https://gist.github.com/ugurayan/f51436e737838df52d92ad70241a5748#file-home-html)

then below error occurs

> > Runtime Error
> >     Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors: The pipe 'myPipe' could not be found ("  {{[ERROR ->]'test1' | myPipe}}  "): ng:///Page1PageModule/Page1Page.html@16:2 Error: Template parse errors: The pipe 'myPipe' could not be found ("  {{[ERROR ->]'test1' | myPipe}}  "):

`Case 2`: If I import `Pipe` file to `Page1Module` and `Page2Module`

- [page1.module.ts](https://gist.github.com/ugurayan/58f62e51daf3c829b3b1a47b9ff7b014#file-page1-module-ts) ( imported [Pipe file](https://gist.github.com/ugurayan/58f62e51daf3c829b3b1a47b9ff7b014#file-my-ts)). We use pipe in [page1.html](https://gist.github.com/ugurayan/58f62e51daf3c829b3b1a47b9ff7b014#file-page1-html)
- [page2.moudel.ts](https://gist.github.com/ugurayan/58f62e51daf3c829b3b1a47b9ff7b014#file-page2-module-ts) ( imported [Pipe file](https://gist.github.com/ugurayan/58f62e51daf3c829b3b1a47b9ff7b014#file-my-ts)). We use pipe in [page2.html](https://gist.github.com/ugurayan/58f62e51daf3c829b3b1a47b9ff7b014#file-page2-html)
- [app.module.ts](https://gist.github.com/ugurayan/58f62e51daf3c829b3b1a47b9ff7b014#file-app-module-ts) ( no import pipe.ts). we use pipe in [home.html](https://gist.github.com/ugurayan/58f62e51daf3c829b3b1a47b9ff7b014#file-home-html)

then below error occurs

> Runtime Error
>   Uncaught (in promise): Error: Type MyPipe is part of the declarations of 2 modules: Page1PageModule and Page2PageModule! Please consider moving MyPipe to a higher module that imports Page1PageModule and Page2PageModule. You can also create a new NgModule that exports and includes MyPipe then import that NgModule in Page1PageModule and Page2PageModule. Error: Type MyPipe is part of the declarations of 2 modules: Page1PageModule and Page2PageModule! Please consider moving MyPipe to a higher module that imports Page1PageModule and Page2PageModule. You can also create a new NgModule that exports and includes MyPipe then import that NgModule in Page1PageModule and Page2PageModule.

Thanks for your recommendations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is very simple. This is my workflow.

1. I create `pipe` using this `CLI`: `ionic generate pipe MyFilter`
2. Then it'll create `pipes.module.ts` automatically.
3. After that, I just `import` it into my lazy loaded page's `module` as below.

*member.module.ts*

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPageModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { MemberPage } from './member';
import { PipesModule } from '../../pipes/pipes.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MemberPage,
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicPageModule.forChild(MemberPage),
    PipesModule <-- here
  ],
})
export class MemberPageModule { }
```

4. That is it. No errors and `pipe` is working perfectly too :)

Comment: I try ionic g pipe myPipe then there is another error occurs `Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/future/temp/example/src/PIPES/pipes.module.ts'
    at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:652:18)` but I add manually a pipe module then it works... thanks for your help...